# Why was decimal time unsuccessful?

Tags: technology, science

Under the metric system (and later SI), units of weight can be related to each other based on multiples of ten (e.g. 1 metric tonne = 1,000 kg = 1,000 × 1,000 g). Likewise with length (e.g. 1 kilometre = 1,000m = 1,000 × 100cm).

The French Revolution introduced these decimal based units of weight and length. It also introduced decimal time, dividing the day into ten hours, each hour into 100 decimal minutes, and each minute into 100 decimal seconds. But while the decimal units of weight and length proved successful and are now used almost everywhere around the world, decimal time is not. Why did decimal time fail?

Some Wikipedia references: [Metric System History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system#History), [Decimal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time).

Comment: Because a yardstick is a lot cheaper than a clock.

Comment: For most people of the era when decimal time was devised, the specific time of day was not as important as the weight, volume or length of items like foodstuffs or trade goods.

Comment: The way I heard it, one day of rest every ten days instead of every seven didn't go down too well either. (No references, sorry)

Comment: 10 can only be divided evenly by 5 and 2. 60 can be divided evently by 30, 20, 15, 12, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3 and 2. I think this speaks for itself :)

Answer (score 20):

They also introduced decimal angle measures (100 degrees in the right angle, each degree is 100 minutes. This explain why the kilometer was originally defined as it was: it is one decimal minute of the Earth's meridian, like the nautical mile is one
ordinary minute of the same).

I can name three reasons why the decimal system for time did not survive. First, people are very conservative in their habits and it is hard to implement such a dramatic change. More people use time measurement and more frequently than any other measures. And the revolutionary regime was not long enough to force French people switch. Decimal time was abandoned at the time of Napoleon or shortly before that. How conservative people are one can see from the example of America where the decimal system was never accepted.

A second reason may be that the common time and angle units are based on a very good sexagesimal (Babylonian) system which is actually more convenient for mental computations than the decimal one. (Because the numbers like 60, 24 and 12 have many divisors unlike 10.) So in some respects it is more rational than the decimal one.

Finally the third reason is that our system of time measurement was universal, accepted almost everywhere in the world (unlike the systems of other measures which varied from country to country at the time when the metric system was introduced). The main gain from the metric system was unification of the units. In the case of time the system was already so unified that nobody felt the need for replacement.

Remark: By the way, the decimal system is not universally accepted. I already mentioned America. Let me also mention the airline industry. Even in an Air France liner made by the Airbus company, the altitude is measured in feet and speed in knots.

Remark 2. In general, decimal system has only one advantage: convenience of counting using fingers. Systems with bases 8 and 12 are more convenient in most other respects.

Remark 3 (8.26.21) It turns out that the use of 12 in time measurement is not related to the number of divisors. 12 comes from the fact of nature that a year consists of approximately 12 months.
So ancient Babylonians divided the Sun's yearly path (ecliptic) into 12 parts (Zodiac signs). Since rising of the parts of ecliptic was used to measure time during night, this led to division of a night
in 6 parts (double hours). Then it was very natural to divide into the same number of parts another circle, the equator. Which led to the division of day+night into 12 "hours" which were later called "double hours". Why and when they decided to divide these "hours" into two halves, is not clear. Moreover, since a month is divided into 30 days,
the same division was applied to the Zodiac signs which led to division of the circle into 12x30=360 degrees.

Thus there is a (well-documented) evidence that 360 was not chosen by "mathematical convenience" but was forced on us by the nature: the approximate number of months in a year times the number of days in a month.

Ref. B. L. van der Waerden, Science Awakening II, Springer 1974.

Comment: +1 mostly for the divisors. a numbers whose (prime) factors are 2*2*3*5 (=60), that is the first three prime numbers, is near magical for easy integer math

Comment: Yet, even today, most scientific calculators offer a choice of degrees, radians, or *grads*, as the unit for angular measure...

Comment: Not all aviation altitudes are in feet. In China, Mongolia, Russia & a number of CIS states flight altitudes are in metres. (Flight Level) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_level]

Comment: More divisors = more rational :) nice pun.

Comment: @Fred: According to the same Wikipedia article, they (Russians and their friends) are switching to feet. Not surprisingly since most of their new airplanes are made by Boeing and Airbus.

Comment: One could also add to the intangible reasons the religious background with a traditional week of 6 work days and 1 day for resting.

Comment: Yes, this is an objection to the revolutionary calendar. But not to the division of day and night into 20 hours.

Comment: BTW, the 10 days week was also briefly introduced in Soviet Union, before WWII. The purpose was to increase the productivity by making people work more. And the fight against religion too.

Comment: A *knot* is **not** an Imperial measurement. One Nautical mile is one minute of latitude, and one knot is one nautical mile per hour. The airline and maritime companies of the world use *knots* to measure speed because of this direct relationship to the shape of the Earth, and the preferred choice of angle and time measurements, not for historical reasons.

Comment: A follow-up question then: why medieval smaller units of time, such as "third" = 1/60 second and "fourth" = 1/60 third, weren't accepted in modern age, and we are using milliseconds etc? One can argue that "third" would be more convenient, at least in USA, where AC power frequency is 1/60 second, and TV refreshes 1/30 second...

Comment: About "switching to feet", that's true **only** for a few specific areas, like aviation that you mentioned, or DPI (dots per inch) in publishing, things like that, with heavy reliance on US-made equipment.

Comment: If divisibility is so important, maybe we should adopt angular time: 360 degrees in a day. It would also have direct correspondence to the astronomical hour angle and time of day on longitudes (simple subtraction).

Comment: @Calmarius: In practical astronomy they do sometimes the opposite for convenience: measure certain angles in time units. (Right ascension, and hour angle, for example).

Comment: Also, while it is true that 12 has more factors than 10, the only important part for a number to not be periodic is the prime factors and 10 and 12 have the same amount of prime factors, 2. 60 has 3 and 24 has 2. BTW, 30 has also 3 and uses fewer numbers than 60...

Comment: @Armin: I do not know what you mean be "periodic number", but I disagree that only prime factors are relevant here. It is convenient to be able to easily divide the day into several equal parts. For example, in many kinds of activities day+night are divided into 8-hour or 4-hour shifts, though neither 4=24/6 not 8=24/3 are primes. How would you divide 20 hours day+night into similar shifts conveniently?

Comment: @Alex a periodic number is one that doesn't have a clear cut-off point. For example 1/3 in base 10 is 0.333... (periodic) while 1/5 is 0.2 (non-periodic). Only the prime factors influence to which of these two categories a number belongs.

Comment: `country to country` it was worse than that - every town had potentially different measures

Comment: "Then it was very natural to divide into the same number of parts another circle, equator. Which led to the division of day+night into 12 "hours"" I don't understand what you're saying here.

Answer (score 12):

Because:

a) time change was more complex than the change of other measures, and

b) in contrast with the other changes, it actually did not impove anything.

Let's go with "a". For dealing with weights, lengths and volumes, sellers would usually have some simple measuring tools, using reference units;

- for measuring lengths of cloth they would have a stick of the appropiate length, and use it to measure the point where to cut.
- for volumes (usually liquids like milk), they would have some jars with the more common units, and fill them to provide the desired quantity (if the customer asked 1 pint and a quarter, you would just have to fill the 1 pint jar and the quarter jar).
- for weights, the most common (and easiest to maintain) tool were the balance scales[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_scale#Balance_scales) with a similar set of measured weights.

Replacing those measures just mean switching those reference units to the new ones (and, I expect, changing the prices proportionally). I remember reading a reference to a French public announcement, telling merchants that they could go to the city hall to change their old yards and half-yards for meters and half meters.

Now, changing time is quite a different thing. Usually, time measuring devices are quite complex; at the time of the French Revolution making [chronometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_chronometer) precise enough for determining the ship position was still "advanced science"; building clocks was expensive enough <sup>1</sup> (even without the need of redesigning the mechanism to match the new "second" definition) that it is easy to find why it was a more difficult change.

Now, for the relevance of the change, think that the beginning of the XIXth, almost every country (and, in big country, almost every region) had its own sets of measures, usually with similar names but variable values. This had a deep impact in commerce; some merchant buying clothes in Antwerp and selling them in Paris had to buy X (belgian) yards of cloth to find that he could sell Y (Parisian) yards of cloth. If there were customs, he would have to know also which measure were used for taxation. As trade increased, standardization was more important<sup>2</sup>.

Now, the same (lack of standards) was true for time keeping, but there was a big difference: before the spread of artificial lighting, timekeeping was inherently a local issue because daily activity depended on sunlight. [Hours] [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour) were set depending of dawn or dusk time; the "timezone" of each town was dictated by the clock (if there was one) or the bells of the church. There was no need for keeping a local timezone, because there was no process that could benefit from it (remember than the "maximum absolute speed" was that of a man on horseback). It was not until the expansion of railways and telegraph that it even began to make sense thinking of synchronization of the different towns.

<sup>1</sup>from the link: `The new technology was initially so expensive that not all ships carried chronometers, as illustrated by the fateful last journey of the East Indiaman Arniston.[14] However by 1825, the Royal Navy had begun routinely supplying its vessels with chronometers.`

<sup>2</sup>Of course, standardization could have been happened with any set of measures, but the metric system had two advantages:

- It was designed as an **universal** system. Instead of some local sizes (the foot of the local King, for example), it was defined in base to natural properties (the size of Earth, the density of water).
- It was a decimal system, which make switching between units way more convenient (80 centimeters where 0.8 meters, instead of 7 inches being 7/12 feet).

Comment: Not really convinced with the chronometers argument. Wouldn't be even harder to change millions of devices (say nowadays) than changing a relatively few? Typically "advanced science" also means still open to change, I guess

Comment: This issue of chronometers/clocks is largely irrelevant. The mechanism for a 12 h clock can be the same as for a 10 h decimal clock; the only thing that needs to change is the face of the clock. Instead of having the #1 @ 30 degrees from the #12 (@ the top of the clock face), as on a conventional clock, on a decimal clock the #1 would be 36 degrees from the #10 (@ the top of the clock face). All your other points are good.

Comment: diary -> daily ?

Comment: I have occasionally seen antique "revolutionary watches" come up on eBay so they clearly existed. You'd need to change the motion work (2 wheels under the dial) as well as the dial itself as it no longer divides by 12.  http://www.e-flux.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/clock-web.jpg?b8c429

Comment: @Fred maybe I have not expressed myself clearly enough, while the basic mechanics would be similar, you would need to adjust all the internal mechanism to match the new definition of second (of different duration) and minutes (100 "new" seconds). If you watch only had the hour "hand" then yes, all that you would need to change it would be to change the marks, but if you had the minutes "hand" you would have to adjust it so it did 100 revolutions for each "hour".

Answer (score 10):

> Why did decimal time fail?

Rhetorical question: Why did the International Standards Organization's (ISO) Open Systems Interconnection (OSI) fail? The answer is that there wasn't a mess that desperately needed to be cleaned up. ISO was a bit late. An *ad hoc* standard was already maturing and taking over. You wrote your question, and I wrote this answer thanks to the people who developed TCP/IP as opposed to the members of the ISO OSI committee.

At the time of the French Revolution, a person traveling from town to town was forced deal with different units of length, area, volume, and mass in each town. On the other hand, that same person could look at a sundial anywhere in western Europe and know what time it was. Time was already standardized across western Europe.

Standards organizations are at their best when there's an absolute mess that desperately needs to be cleaned up. Standards organizations are at their worst when things are already nice and tidy, but perhaps in an *ad hoc* way. Time was already nice and tidy (but perhaps in an *ad hoc* way) at the time of the French Revolution.

At the time of the French Revolution, time had already been standardized in an *ad hoc* way for a long, long time. The concept of dividing a day and a night into twelve hours dates back to ancient Egypt. The concept of dividing an hour into sixty minutes and a minute into sixty seconds is based on how we measure angle, which dates back to ancient Babylonia. The concept of a day divided into twenty four hours, which in turn were divided into sixty minutes, which in turn was divided into sixty seconds, was quite entrenched and quite standard.

**TL;DR:** "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: Exactly correct!  Decimal time was all pain, no gain.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition (or an extended comment) to other answers.

I wouldn't say that people being conservative could not change time units quickly. They use time measurements everyday, it is more often than eg. measuring distances, however, people use money everyday also very often. Most money reforms (the largest are converting to euro in EU countries) takes at most two-five years. So it is not a big endeavor. And the time switch would also not be (if related to brains only, the financial effort would be large), but it should allow to use two units of time in parallel (eg. "old hours" and "new hours", or maybe "hour" and "dour" - "decimal hour"). The calendar switches were performed and nothing bad happened.

What is most important here, is that in fact no-one can force anybody to abandon the old unit. A government can make you use new money by removing the old ones from the market. Of course, it can punish for using "hours" instead of "dours", but it wouldn't be accepted by people in democracies.

The time reform would also be difficult, as it should be performed worldwide, probably in the very same moment. This is difficult and requires lots of effort. There are many things that are time-dependent, in today's era software, which 1. has to be modified, 2. has to be verified and tested, 3. has to be introduced at once, 4. should understand older time, 5. should be rapairable (support for **all devices** would require lots of people, and this is sure that software would have bugs). Also, there are devices that use time not to count your worktime, but which guard and control power plants, trains, planes, nuclear weapon etc. Do you remember the "Year 2K problem"? Even if all the measurements taken were not necessary, you can remember the effort that was taken.

The option why people are conservative is in fact the life experience "if it works relatively good, why should I change it?". Everyone knows that any small modification of a system is a risk of big collapse. The only problem with 24 hours a day (not 10 or 100) is when you need to calculate some time difference - how long did something last? But it's quite easy to convert parts of an hour to minutes, as someone mentioned, 60 is very good number for division, it has many dividers (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30), having 2, 5, 10, 20 - all the necessary that one use most often (take a look to your wallet and see, what bills / bank notes you have). Would it be easy to divide an hour on three parts if it had 100 minutes?

The main problem with time is then only when calculating time differences - how often do you perform it daily? How many times have you a problem to calculate "it started 4:45, ended 7:08, how long did it last?" Damn, that's easy: there are eight minutes between 7:00 and 7:08, fifteen minutes between 4:45 and 5:00, so together 8+15=23, there are three hours between 4 and 7, so 3 hours minus 60-37=23 minutes is 2 hours and 37 minutes. Is this really harder than subtracting from 100? How often do you need to solve "how much time are 157 minutes?" And - how often you need to know exact difference? Most people would say "about two and half hours".

This revolution could have been made before, for example 200 years ago, or even in Renaissance - not now. Would it be possible for the United Kingdom to switch from the left-side-driving? There are so many cars to be changed, so many traffic signs... (IIRC Sweden did it in the beginning of 1960s. as the last country). But is it necessary for the UK to do this swap? Who would benefit? How would this change pay back? When?

So the reason is that it in fact is not necessary. People do not have problems with this. Only those who count time, and software engineers who code software for them. I suppose this is a minority in each population.

Comment: Samoa changed from right- to left-hand traffic in 2009.

Comment: @Voitcus "This revolution could have been made before, for example 200 years ago" - The question is not about a change now but about a tried change 200 years ago. So your answer misses the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can express a quarter or a third of an hour in integer number of minutes (15, 20 respectively).

The same with the day: a quarter of a day is 6 hours, a third of a day is 8 hours.

For the same reasons, it is much more convenient to measure angle by dividing circle into 360 degrees: you can express angles like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/3, 1/6, 1/12, 1/9, 1/5, 1/10, 1/20, 1/30, 1/40 of a circle in integer amount of degrees.

Comment: But the same logic applies with measuring other things, such as length or volume.  For everyday use, binary (halves, quarters, &c) or duodecimal (six-packs or dozens) often works better.  I suspect that with time, the major problem was with changing the orbits of the Earth and moon so as to make days, months, and years fit into a decimal scheme :-)

Comment: @jamesqf the French revolution in fact considered switching to duodecimal (12-based) system. But decimal system is historical for Indo-European peoples, for instance, the numerals in languages are 10-based. This is since 3500-4000 BC.

Comment: But even in metricified countries, people still use the binary & duodecimal when convenient, for instance you can buy a half kilo of butter,  six-packs of drinks, and eggs by the dozen.